# Easy backup VPS server

Tags: mysql, linux, database, backup, administration

I have VPS (with Ubuntu Server). Files and DBs are not very large (~10-20 GB totally) but I need to make periodic backups of all user data.

I'm looking for simple solutions that allows to backup all this stuff to Amazon S3, and meet some conditions:

- Easy to configure, because I'm newbie in server administration
- Backup all files (entirely /home directory)
- Backup MySQL DB
- Incremental weekly backups

Could you give advice for my case or recommend good tools for such backups?

Comment: I think you would get better results over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) - I'm not doubting the SO user skillset, it just seems like a question more suited over there.

Answer (score 0):

[backupninja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/backupninja) maybe is what you want. Also, you may be interested in [backup gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup). [Backup manager](http://www.r1soft.com/server-backup-manager) by R1 soft also good choice.

And take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208/whats-the-best-linux-backup-solution?rq=1), it has a several other backup solutions.